# Problemas al chequear Inputs vacios con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo problemas al chequear inputs con jQuery, lo que quería es que al ver contenido dentro de los inputs hiciera la función que es añadirle style al *div (locked)*, de lo contrario que no funcione. Pero no me funciona el código que hice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#success').click(function() {
            if(
                $('#username').val() > 0 &&
                $('#password').val() > 0
                ){
                var div = document.getElementById('locked');
                div.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        });

//Inputs
<input type="text" name="username" id="orange" id="username" placeholder="Introduce tu usuario..." autofocus required>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="orange" id="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña..." required>
                            <button type="submit" name="login" class="button" id="success">Conectarme</button>
```

Comment: ¿podrias poner tu ejemplo completo?, porque no veo el div  locked. Tambien buscas los inputo por id pero  tiene id="orange" en ambos inputs antes del id="username" y del id="password" lo cual es el problema al obtener los elementos. Saludos

Comment: Corríge tu enunciado, estas mostrando un input con doble `id`. `<input type="text" name="username" id="orange" id="username".....`

Comment: Tambien veo que estas validando que el valor sea  mayor a 0, pero tus input admiten texto, por lo  cual creo que sera mas correcto validad la longitud del contenido del input  $('#username').val().length > 0,  ya que validarias por numero de caracteres.

Comment: Gracias a todos, no me había percatado que tenía otro id, ya lo solucioné.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes usar `length`, es decir, en vez de colocar

```
$('#username').val() > 0
```

debes comparar

```
$('#username').val().length > 0
```

Y lo mismo para el otro `input`